# How to integrate Module.symvers while compiling a Module

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, kernel

I have a Module.symvers files which has the symbols (from Module A) I need to use in other module say B.
But I cant make changes to the original module A. Is there a way to tell Module B, to get symbols as per the Module.symvers file.

I have included it in my build directory, its still gives be undefined symbols error while compiling module A.
Appreciate your help.

Comment: 1. I assume it is a misprint above and the error shows up when building `B` rather than `A`, doesn't it? 2. Are the symbols you need from `A` actually listed in its `.symvers` file? 3. Did you copy `.symvers` file as is or with a different name and used KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS or the like?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this solution helps you.

Export symbol from module A as **EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(symbol)**
In module B, use them after declaring **MODULE_LICENSE("GPL")**.Don't forget to include those symbol declarations in module B.

Comment: If the symbols are present in that `Module.symvers` from module A, they are probably exported already. If they are not present, yes, the author of A seems not to have exported them.